# What does an embedding over $K$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, normal-extension

I have some understanding problem.
In the topic of extensions they always speak about embeddings over some field $K$ and i have absolutly no idea what this means. One example is the following:

> Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $k$ contained in an algebraic closure $k^a$ of $k$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. Every embedding of $K$ in $k^a$ over $k$ induces an automorphism of K
> 2. ...
> 3. ...
>
> So but what does this exaclty mean? from where to where does the embedding goes?

Another example is the following.

> Assume that $K\supset E\supset k$ and that $K$ is normal over $k$. Let $\sigma$ be an embedding of $K$ over $E$...
>
> What does this mean in this case?

Thanks for your help because I'm really confused with the formualtion and it's meaning

Comment: In this context, an embedding of a field $F$ into a field $E$ is just an injective field homomorphism $i \colon F \to E$. In fact, if you require (as many do) that ring homomorphisms are unital, then every homomorphism of fields injective, so this extra label is superfluous, and an embedding is just a homomorphism of fields.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it just means that $k\to k^a$ and $k\to K\to k^a$ are the same map.

Comment: @AlexWertheim and what does it mean in the first example

Comment: Oh, whoops. I misread your question - sorry about that. In general, suppose we are given rings $R, S, T$, and ring homomorphisms $f \colon R \to S, g \colon R, \to T$. A ring morphism $h \colon S \to T$ over $R$ is a ring homomorphism $h \colon S \to T$ such that $h \circ f = g$.

Comment: perfect thanks!